# Calculating Fields in Controller - Better Ways?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

Thanks for your eyes on my issue. I'm hoping to get feedback on a better way to approach a solution!

Here's my situation: I have a Visualforce page and corresponding controller that looks at a series of hiring requests and determines the status of those hiring requests. However, the 'status' in the visualforce page doesn't have a corresponding database field. Instead, status is calculated inside the controller.

Here's a simplified version of my query:

```
SELECT Id,
       (Select Offer_Status__c from Offers__r),
       (Select Review_Status__cfrom Employee_File__r)
FROM Hire_Request__c
WHERE conditions
```

Then, for each of the returned hire requests, I run through a few conditions and determine the request's status based on the existence of child objects. Essentially:

```
for (hire : hires) {
    if employee_file__r.size() > 0 {
        hire.status__c = 'Hired';
    } else if offers__r.size() > 0 {
        hire.status__c = 'Offer sent';
    } else {
        hire.status__c = 'Ready for offer';
```

Now, the truth is that status__c tracks other data and I don't actually save the updates to the database; instead, I just display them on the Visualforce page.

Hire_request__c isn't the master object for the two children, so I can't rely on summary fields to determine the status. If I were to track the status in the database, I'd need to rely on a series of triggers, which would fire when each of the three objects referenced above change.

Is there anything patently wrong with doing calculations in a controller? Is there a better way to go about solving my issue? I certainly appreciate any thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting key information in the data model makes things like global search, list view filtering, related lists in default layout-based UI, default layout-based detail pages, reports and dashboards, external access of the data model all possible and useful.

Calculating on the fly in one page/controller means that is the only place the information will be seen which is likely to be limiting in the long run as the platform features listed above won't then be available to you and your users.

So if the status is important in your system, it would be a good investment to get it reliably present in the data model by whatever means you can. If you can refactor to create the master-detail relationship (assuming that is also appropriate in the domain model sense) then do so.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! This is useful context for me to hear -- I _can_ do this calculation in the controller, but there are a number of drawbacks and I'm not going to be able to use the status anywhere but in the particular Visualforce page which depends on the controller. Unfortunately, refactoring the relationship type isn't an option but adding triggers with status updates is. Appreciate the thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using master-detail relationships, you can use rollup summary fields on the Hire_Request__c object, which would then reduce your entire complexity to a formula field:

```
IF(Employee_File_Count__c > 0, 
  'Hired', 
  IF(Offer_Count__c > 0, 
    'Offer Sent', 
    'Ready for Offer'
  )
)
```

If you're not using master-detail relationships, or otherwise can't manage them (e.g. you have to many other rollups present), you could use triggers to roll up the summary; this would trade the page's loading time in exchange for the time needed to save records (this could be a significant gain).

Basically, the trigger on Employee_File__c would update the Hire_Request__c record to 'Hired' status, and the trigger on the Offer__c record would update the status to 'Offer Sent' as long as the status was in the 'Ready for Offer' status.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I'm restricted from using master-detail relationships because this is actually from a managed package, so the relationships are set in stone. I could add triggers though, which would be a promising refactoring path. Appreciate the insights!